# Syntax in Lightning Button/URL to set date field on object from Date/Time field on starting Object?

Tags: custom-button, custom-url, date-field

I have created a custom button Type=DetailPage & Content=URL on the Event Object. This button creates a new Custom Object named Registration record.
One of the fields that needs to be set on the Registration record during creation is a date field (there are actually 2 date fields) and that needs to be set from the Events custom Date field. I have it working, in regards to populating the data in the Registration fields BUT..when trying to Save it gives and error as if it doesn't realize it's there. Once you click into the fields, it satisfies the validation. Not sure if it's something in my syntax.
Here are the button details, with the 2 date field lines highlighted:
[image]

And here is what the New Registration screen looks like after clicking Save and using the custom button:
[image]

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to correct this?

Comment: Hi please check this https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/tree/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/navToNewRecordWithDefaults . you should use navigation this URL hack is not a good idea to start

Comment: did you try: `End__c={!DATEVALUE(Event.EndDateTime)}` ?

Comment: @cropredy : I did replace my line End__c={!URLENCODE(TEXT(Event.EndDateTime))},               with yours End__c={!DATEVALUE(Event.EndDateTime)}                                                  but I still get the validation error saying that End Date needs to be populated even though it is

Comment: @Avijit Chakraborty: I understand the URL hacks are not a good idea but I needed to replace an existing button that was a Classic URL hack during a lightning migration project I am working on. Someone previously (long gone) created it and I just wanted to quickly replicate something that was supported in Lightning. I am not a developer so I am limited on what I can do. I'm not sure what the link to github could do for me? I'm unsure how to use that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `{!URLENCODE(TEXT(Event.EndDateTime))}`, the time value is being sent "silently" to the date field, hence the validation error even though visually the only date portion is visible.
You can try the formula into a text field to see this.

Note that `{!URLENCODE(TEXT(Event.EndDateTime))}` can cause incorrect date formatting when passing value to date field.

To fix your issue use this formula by converting to date first:

`End__c={!URLENCODE(TEXT(DATEVALUE(Event.EndDateTime)))},`

Comment: are you saying I need to create a new formula field and use that new field to populate the date on the new record?

Comment: @user7417 no need to create a new formula field. in your existing custom url formula, just replace formula with the fix provided in answer for end__c and start__c accordingly

Comment: That was it, thanks! So I needed the additional "DATEVALUE" in my formula. All good info to know. Thanks you so much for getting me over the finish line with this.